# Can't run jupyter notebook after installation

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

[when i run jupyter notebook i got this error again after all commands ][3]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYgoN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will reinstall everything from pypi.

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter
```

Then Try to use this command to run you notebook as your terminal also suggested.

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: i tryed , but i got same result

Comment: trace back is same as previous screen shot ?

Comment: Ok i have checked, first exit from venv then try to run your jupyter notebook.

Comment: type `deactivate`, then again run this command `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter` and then run jupyter notebook.

Comment: Have you deactivate your venv?

Comment: If yes and still problem occurs that try to make new venv then install notebook and then run it.

Comment: How i can deactivate venv?

Comment: After deactivation of your venv have you reinstall it or not ?

Comment: If your problem isn't solving, then we can video call eachother to see your problem

Comment: so what about video call ? can you share your screen with me?

Comment: We can use TemViewer,you can see problem and do something

Comment: nikolaychik.nastenka@gmail.com

Comment: check your mail

Comment: I tried the `pip install` command, and I get this: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\spyder\\python\\lib\\site-packages\\~~rnado\\speedups.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.`

Comment: @Ilya did you try pip3 install?

Comment: No, I didn't. I switched to WinPython (although I don't remember the exact reason).